# Loading images into HTML Canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a set of svg images and some attributes that I would like to load onto an HTML Canvas.  The goal is to have the images loaded at the given size, and onto the given x,y coordinates.   Here is my example object:

```
var ObjectInstances = {
objects:[
    {
    "ID": "1234",
    "Name": "Backhoe",
    "x": "0",
    "y": "0",
    "height": "150",
    "width": "350",
    "svg": "images/svgs/backhoe.svg"
    },
    {
    "ID": "5678",
    "Name": "Crane",
    "x": "350",
    "y": "150",
    "height": "200",
    "width": "200",
    "svg": "images/svgs/crane1.svg"
    }
] 
};
```

Optimally I would loop through the objects, and use these key:value pairs to render each image onto the canvas, but I continually run into instances where the objects appear at different sizes, or in different locations after reload.  I know from my research that I have to preload all the images in order to draw the them on the canvas. I've created parallel arrays to handle this.  One array to hold the preloaded images, the other array to hold the coordinates and sizes of each image. Then I have attempted to draw the images using these two arrays.  Here is my code:

```
function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
    numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
    images[src] = new Image();
    images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
        callback(images);
        }
    };
    images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
}

// Preload images into a source array
var sources = {};
$.each(ObjectInstances.objects, function(index, value) {
        sources[index]=this.svg;
})

loadImages(sources, function(images) {

$.each(ObjectInstances.objects, function (index, value) {
    var x=$(this)[0].x,
        y=$(this)[0].y,
        w=$(this)[0].width,
        h=$(this)[0].height;
    attach(images[index], x, y, w, h);

});

});


// Load Object Instances

function attach(img, x, y, w, h) {
    context.drawImage(img, x, y, w, h);
}
```

Can someone guide me here as to the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't separate the image elements from their meta object. I would do something like this using a single array:

```
var ObjectInstances = {
objects:[
    {
    "ID": "1234",
    "Name": "Backhoe",
    "x": "0",
    "y": "0",
    "height": "150",
    "width": "350",
    "svg": "images/svgs/backhoe.svg",
    image: null
    },
    {
    "ID": "5678",
    "Name": "Crane",
    "x": "350",
    "y": "150",
    "height": "200",
    "width": "200",
    "svg": "images/svgs/crane1.svg",
    image: null
    }
] 
};
```

Then iterate over the array to invoke the loading by its url:

```
loadImage(ObjectInstances, myCallback);

function loadImages(obj, callback) {

    var i = 0,
        o,
        count = obj.objects.length;

    for(; o = obj.objects[i]; i++) {
        o.image = new Image(o.width, o.height);
        o.image.onload = loader;
        o.image.src = o.svg;
    }

    function loader() {
        count--;
        if (count === 0) callback({
            objectInstances: obj
        });
    }
}
```

Now when you iterate over your original array you will have valid image elements directly attached to the object itself (unless an error occurred of course in which case the callback is never called as the code stands here - add onerror/onabort event handlers to deal with this situation).

Notice that I set width and height using the optional `Image`'s arguments as we're dealing with SVG (not necessary but may help in the rasterizing process). This dimension is read by the properties with the same names while the original dimension is read by using `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`.

Modify as needed. Hope this helps.

Comment: This has been very helpful. I put a version into JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sPHjd/  with my drawToCanvas function on the callback. It seems to work perfectly- every time.  In my larger solution I still get various renderings, but at least I know its not caused by this part of the code.